# Is adding and subtracting vectors different from adding and subtracting normal values

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I expected these two calculations to have the same outcome:

One:

```
let steering = createVector();
let diff = position1
steering.sub(position2);
steering.add(diff)
```

Two:

```
let steering = createVector();
let diff = position1
diff.sub(position2);
steering.add(diff)
```

This worked, but I don't understand why:

```
let steering = createVector();
let diff = position1
diff = p5.Vector.sub(position2)
steering.add(diff)
```

Where one would basically be:

```
0-position2+position1
```

And two would be:

```
0+(position1-position2)
```

`position1` and `position2` are p5 vectors.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, but sub and add are not normal js operators, they are methods of the vector-objects.

Comment: Ah well you see I have completely failed at reading your question :)

Comment: OK now that I look at it, no I don't think those operations will be the same. I'll think about how to come up with an answer that's not nonsense.

Comment: I think `p5.Vector.sub()` with one parameter doesn't make a lot of sense ...

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that shows the input and output?

Comment: Well after setting up my own version in the sandbox, I think I *do* get the same end result for `steering`. Is that what you're concerned about?

Comment: @KevinWorkman that's kind of hard given the nature of `p5.js` "programs".

Comment: Do you have some test values for `position1` and `position2` where `steering` does *not* come out the way you expect?

Comment: @Pointy No, it's not.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I don't understand that context without context. I've already commented that I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never use

```
someVector = someOtherVector;
```

This can cause a lot of problems, because you are not actually making another vector object.
Consider this:

```
let someVector = createVector(1, 1);
let someOtherVector = someVector;
someOtherVector.sub(createVector(1, 1));

print(someVector.equals(someOtherVector)); //this will return true, which should not be the case.
```

to fix this, use `let someOtherVector = someVector.copy()` instead.

I tried reproducing your issue, but it seems to work:

```
function setup() {
  let steering = createVector(6, 9);
  let position1 = createVector(5, 7);
  let position2 = createVector(2, 3);

  let diff = position1.copy();
  steering.sub(position2);
  steering.add(diff);

  print(steering);
}
```